# Identify this game: duplicates

Tags: discussion, game-identification, exact-duplicates

What to do with `identify-this-game` duplicates? The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24173/identify-this-isometric-wizard-platformer-on-pc) is the same as [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/early-90s-dos-action-adventure-game-with-an-isometric-view-that-is-similar-to-the), but the descriptions that users gave were a bit different. Do we have to close it as duplicate or not?

Comment: As if I needed another reason to hate these putrid game identification questions. Hate, hate, *hate*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're identify-this-game for the same game... it's basically a no-brainer, they *are* duplicates.

Remember that:

- Closed questions can still be linked to.
- Closed questions can still be voted on.
- Closed questions can still be googled.
- Closed questions can still award reputation.

The only thing closing does is not allowing any further answers... a point that is moot: in this case we know what the answer is. No further answers can really add anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would necessarily apply to all such duplicates, but this was the concern I had in this particular instance. Here are the titles in question:

- Early-90s DOS action/adventure game with an isometric view that is similar to the view in Puzzle Quest 2
- Identify this isometric wizard platformer on PC

Searching the site only on "isometric" would have brought up the earlier question and thus removed the need for the second question; searching on "isometric wizard" would have brought up the other question as the first hit.

If poorly-worded [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) questions are closed (pending addition of enough information to give us a chance to answer), it seems to me that it would be very unlikely that two questions would ask about the same game in enough detail to stay open while not providing enough similar details to allow one author to find the other question.

So that's why I flagged it with a suggestion to close as duplicate.

Answer (score -3):

Let it be because people use it? It does not matter if there are redundant tags if it helps some people to express their idea. My 2 cents.